# Unable to export full GWT celltable data to excel when pagination is implemented

Tags: gwt, servlets

I have a GWT application where I have some data in CellTable. I am trying to export the celltable to excel using gwt-table-to-excel utility. The data is exported fine. But my problem is I have pagination implemented. If I set a page size as 25, I am able to export only that 25 records to excel.

Is there any utility available in gwt that will help me export the entire cellTable data rather than only the ones present in the current page. The cell table is populated in an asynchronous way.

I also tried another approach where I will update the entries in another celltable exclusively for the excel export. This time around I was able to export some 50 odd records even though the page size is only 25. But when I tried to export 100 records present in Celltable I got the following exception

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Form too large209286>200000
at org.mortbay.jetty.Request.extractParameters(Request.java:1404)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Request.getParameter(Request.java:749)
at com.googlecode.gwtTableToExcel.server.TableToExcelServlet.export(TableToExcelServlet.java:68)
at com.googlecode.gwtTableToExcel.server.TableToExcelServlet.doPost(TableToExcelServlet.java:64)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:487)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:362)
at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:181)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:729)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:405)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.RequestLogHandler.handle(RequestLogHandler.java:49)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:324)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:505)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:843)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:647)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:211)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:380)
at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:395)
at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:488)
```

Can someone please tell me how to set maxFormContentsize. I am using servlets. Is there any parameter that can be set in web.xml? Or is there any other utility in GWT that will enable excel export of entire data even though pagination is implemented?

Please guide me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

After setting the VM arguments to 
    -Dorg.mortbay.jetty.Request.maxFormContentSize=4000000
it worked fine in eclipse. In tomcat after setting the same in JAVA_OPTS option it worked fine.